# Not able to create partner jar

Tags: integration, soap-api, java, partner-wsdl

Please note I have checked previously posted questions related to this topic, but my issue is not resolved. All the related and required jar files are in one folder (C:\SOAP) and I run below command, getting below exception:

c:\SOAP>java -classpath tools.jar; force-wsc-53.0.0-uber.jar; ST4-4.0.8.jar; com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc Partner.wsdl Partner.jar
[WSC][wsdlc.main:72]Generating Java files from schema ...
[WSC][wsdlc.main:72]Generated 696 java files.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sforce.ws.codegen.Compiler.(Compiler.java:48)
at com.sforce.ws.codegen.Generator.compileTypes(Generator.java:136)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this.
Changed PATH variable to point to my java installation directory which was was pointing to Oracle\Java\javapath
Removed that and partner.jar created successfully.